# Using all Input Variables in neuralnet in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm trying to create a simple Neural Network in R using the nerualnet package.  Instead of typing out all 784 input variables I am just using a . like is suggested in this thread: [neural network using all input variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779667/neural-network-using-all-input-variables)

But I am getting this error

```
> digitnet <- neuralnet(label ~ ., trainingset, hidden = 4)
```

> Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data'
>   argument

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why that doesn't work but you can always use the following:

```
myform <- as.formula(paste0('label ~ ', 
                             paste(names(trainingset[!names(trainingset) %in% 'label']),
                     collapse = ' + ')))
```

and then:

```
digitnet <- neuralnet(myform, trainingset, hidden = 4)
```

And it will use all 784 input variables in the neural network model.